# My custom matcher is not debuggable when running in intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, hamcrest

I'm wondering if I have a syntax error or mistake?

I have this assertion in my test:

```
    verify(myHttpClient).updateConfig(anyString(),anyString(),
            argThat(new OnlySpecificCountryInPropertiesHasChangedMatcher(countryGasStationConfig, originalProps)),
            anyObject(), anyObject());
```

and this is my custom matcher:

```
public class OnlySpecificCountryInPropertiesHasChangedMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> {

    private final CountryGasStationConfig expectedDelta;
    private final Map<String, String> originalConfiguration;
    private final StringUtils stringUtils;
    private final ListUtils listUtils;


    public OnlySpecificCountryInPropertiesHasChangedMatcher(CountryGasStationConfig expected, Map<String, String> originalVenuesConfigStr) {
        this.expectedDelta = expected;
        this.originalConfiguration = originalVenuesConfigStr;
        this.stringUtils = new StringUtils();
        this.listUtils = new ListUtils();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object actual) {
        System.out.println("in matches");

//some code
}
```

When i run the test in debug in the intellij

The breakpoint in the matcher constructor is called

but the break point in the `matches` method is not called.

and the system-out-print is never printed and it seems the test passed (but I think it's never called)

When I run `./gradlew test` the system-out-print is not printed but the test fails.

Comment: `ArgumentMatcher` seems not to be a hamcrest class. To me it looks like that it comes from a mocking-framework. Which one are you using?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer indeed, it looks like a mockito matcher. How does your test fail? Can you share a log message, a comparison/matcher failure matcher and your full test class, although a [sscce](http://sscce.org) would be even more helpful...